# Нужна ли запятая между частями и почему?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая между частями и почему? С каждый годом ухудшается экология и возрастает статистика заболеваемости.

Comment: Экология — область знания, наука. Что там у вас ухудшается ежегодно?

Comment: @shampar  Экология - также природа и вообще среда обитания всего живого (обычно о плохом их состоянии). Заботы об экологии. Нарушенная э. (Большой толковый словарь)

Comment: «Ухудшается экология» — не о чём. Экология всегда конкретна: экология территории, экология мегаполиса, экология дельты реки. Из текста видно, что «ухудшается экология ... заболеваемости».

Comment: @shampar. По-моему, Вы слишком придирчивы.  Конечно, "экология чего-то" в данном случае лучше, чем просто "экология", но просто "экология" тоже допустима. Между "экология" и "заболеваемости" достаточно слов, чтобы по смыслу фразы понять, что они не связаны. Другими словами, ухудшается состояние окр. среды и возрастает число болезней. Где, в каком регионе - надо искать в контексте.

Comment: Еврика! Самый подходяший термин - "экологическая обстановка". Под экологической обстановкой понимается конкретное состояние окружающей человека среды, обусловленное взаимодействием природы и хозяйственной деятельности человека (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Здесь все придирчивы, и это нормально. Где же, если не здесь? «Слишком» случается с обсуждения субъекта, а не предмета. А предмет здесь (цитата) нижайшего уровня. Если автор услышит «придирку», может быть в следующем его вопросе мы увидим не безграмотный текст, а ради качества вопроса — слегка отредактированный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, запятая не нужна, так как есть общий член, относящийся к обеим частям сложносочиненного предложения, -- "с каждым годом":

> С каждый годом ухудшается экология и возрастает статистика заболеваемости.

Подробнее тут: http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=353.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна, но выражение "возрастает статистика" очень проблематично, возможно, совсем неприемлемо.

Из "Большого толкового словаря": **СТАТИСТИКА**, -и; ж. [нем. Statistik] 1. Совокупность наук, исследующих количественные показатели развития жизни общества во всём её многообразии (экономики, культуры, морали, политики и т.п.) в неразрывной связи с их качественным содержанием. 2. Количественный учёт в какой-л. области народного хозяйства, общественной жизни, осуществляемый методами этой науки; данные этого учёта. Железнодорожная с. Сельскохозяйственная с. С. рождаемости. Отраслевые статистики. Социальная с. 3. Научный метод количественных исследований, применяемый в ряде наук. Звёздная с. Математическая с. (раздел математики, посвящённый математическим методам систематизации, обработки и использования статистических данных для научных и практических выводов). Лингвистическая с. (изучение количественных закономерностей естественного языка, проявляющихся в текстах). <Статистический, -ая, -ое. С-ое наблюдение. С-ая проверка гипотез. С-ие таблицы.

Чем плохо: **возрастает число заболеваний** или, с упором на статистику, **возрастает регистрируемое число заболеваний**, **статистика показывает рост числа заболеваний**

**Дополнение**

Выражение "ухудшается экология" мне кажется приемлемым, но строго говоря, нужно 
писать "**ухудшается экологическая обстановка**".

Под *экологической обстановкой* понимается конкретное состояние окружающей человека среды, обусловленное взаимодействием природы и хозяйственной деятельности человека ([Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Comment: _...но выражение "возрастает статистика" очень проблематично, возможно, совсем неприемлемо._ === Хм! А ведь Вы правы!